# Concatenate IIF/CASE statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to concatenate the outcomes of the IIF statements in SQL Server that are like the example below:

```
SELECT
 IIF(Column1 = 'Yes', 'Yup',
 IIF(Column2 = 'Maybe', 'Perhaps'
 IIF(Column3 = 'No', 'Nope', 'Else')))
FROM TABLE
```

I already tried using the + sign in between the IIF statements, but it didn't work really. But the outcome should be 'Yup Perhaps Nope' if Column1,2,3 are filled in 'Yes', 'Maybe' and 'No'respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
SELECT
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(
                   IIF(Column1 = 'Yes', 'Yup', ' '),
                   IIF(Column2 = 'Maybe', 'Perhaps',' '),
                   IIF(Column3 = 'No', 'Nope', ' ')
          )))
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: It does work, although I was looking for a different answer. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks TriV, 
But I think I found the answer while I was waiting for a response:

```
SELECT
 IIF((Column1 = 'Yes'), 'Yup',NULL)+
 IIF((Column2 = 'Maybe'), 'Perhaps',NULL)+
 IIF((Column3 = 'No'), 'Nope', 'Else')
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Change NULL to '' or it will evaluate to NULL for any FALSE values.

Comment: Why is that a problem cloudsafe?

Comment: If your any IIF statement returns NULL than result would be return null. So its better to use '' in string manipulation as @cloudsafe mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I will implement it :)